# Eisenbud Exercise on schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

I was trying to solve exercise 1.24 part b) of Eisenbud's book on Schemes and to deduce from it an example of locally ringed space which is not an affine scheme. However I am having many problems in one computation

> Consider the affine scheme (Spec($\mathbb C[x,y],O_{Spec\mathbb C[x,y]})$ and set $U=D(x)\cup D(y)$ and say $O$ is the restriction sheaf to $U$. I want to prove that $(U,O)$ is not an affine scheme. To do so, I would like to compute $O(U)$ which should be $\mathbb C[x,y]$ according to the text. How can I prove this? How can I deduce from this that the pair $(U,O)$ is not an affine scheme?

I mean, an element of $O(U)$ is a function from $D(x)\cup D(y)$ into the disjoint union of $\mathbb C[x,y]_{p}$ where $p$ is a prime ideal not containing $x,y$. But from this I really don't see an isomorphism to $\mathbb C[x,y]$. I tried to use the sheaf axioms but I failed.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections of $D(x)$ are elements of the localized rings: $\frac{p(x,y)}{x^n}$ for some $p \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Your sections of $U$ are rational functions that are sections of $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ at the same time... this is exactly $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Now you use the correspondence between affine schemes and rings. The ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is already taken by $\mathbb{A}^2$, so there's no room for $D(x) \cup D(y) = \mathbb{A}^2 \backslash \{0\}$ to be affine.

Comment: Ok but how can I prove that if  $f\in \mathbb C[x,y,1/x]$ and $g\in \mathbb C[x,y,1/y]$ such that they coincides in $\mathbb C[x,y,1/(xy)]$ then they must be equal and belong to $\mathbb C[x,y]$ ?

Comment: @Blacksmith If they coincide then they're equal... there's no need to overthink this. The second question: sections of $D(x)$ are polynomial in $y$ for fixed $x$, and sections of $D(y)$ are polynomial in $x$ for fixed $y$; to be both at once they must be in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the end of your answer: I mean we found out that $O(U)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x,y]$, not equal. So how exactly can we use the correspondence to conclude?

Comment: I mean, if for absurd we assume that $(U,O)$ is an affine scheme, then it means there is a pair $(Spec(R),O_{Spec(R)})$, for some commutative ring $R$, isomorphic to it as locally ringed space. By the correspondence, this induces an isomorphism to $(O_{Spec(R)}(Spec(R))\to O(U)$. Ho do we conclude by this?

Comment: @Blacksmith The correspondence is more precise; given a fixed morphism of rings (here it's the identity $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]$) in particular it tells you what the function on underlying sets is; here it has to be the inclusion. That's not a bijection since $D(x) \cup D(y)$ doesn't contain the origin.

Comment: Actually I am not convinced by your argument to prove that $f$ and $g$ belong to $\mathbb C[x,y]$. Could you give me more details?

Comment: @Blacksmith Try taking a Taylor expansion... as a section on $D(y)$, $f$ has no negative powers of $x$, while as a section on $D(x)$ it has no negative powers of $y$.

Comment: @Blacksmith I had to work out the full gory algebraic details to convince myself, so here they are. Let $f=\frac{r}{x^{i}}\in\mathbb{C}[x,y,1/x]$ and $g=\frac{s}{y^{j}}\in\mathbb{C}[x,y,1/y]$. Then $f$ and $g$ restrict to $\frac{y^{i}r}{(xy)^{i}}$, $\frac{x^{j}s}{(xy)^{j}}$ respectively in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,1/xy]$. These are equal iff $x^{j}y^{i+j}r=x^{i+j}y^{j}s\iff y^{j}r=x^{i}s$. But this is only possible if $r$ is of the form $x^{i}r'$ and $s$ is of the form $y^{j}s'$, in which case $f=\frac{x^{i}r'}{x^{i}}=r'\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $g=\frac{y^{j}s'}{y^{j}}=s'\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $r'=s'$.

Comment: I realise it's nice to aspire to "not overthinking" this stuff and once you develop a certain amount of familiarity, a certain amount of confidence comes with it too. But at the moment I'm trying to do everything the absolute official way, so this is what I have ended up with.